# What is relative jump?

Tags: delphi, assembly, page-jump

Why it is used to hook and redirect functions?

Like this:

```
procedure RedirectProcedure(OldAddress, NewAddress: Pointer);
var
  NewCode: TInstruction;
begin
  NewCode.Opcode := $E9; //relative jump
  NewCode.Offset := NativeInt(NewAddress)-NativeInt(OldAddress)-SizeOf(NewCode);
  PatchCode(OldAddress, NewCode, SizeOf(NewCode));
end;
```

By the way, what $E9 constant means?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697877/relative-vs-absolute-jmp-in-assembly

Comment: $E9 is a 32 bit relative jump instruction - [JMP in assembler language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMP_(x86_instruction))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A jump instruction moves the instruction pointer to a new location. It's the machine language equivalent of goto. Absolute jumps move the instruction pointer to an absolute address. A relative jump jumps to an address specified relative to the current instruction pointer.

The $E9 opcode is a relative jump with a 32 bit offset. Note that there are different jump opcodes for jumps with differently sized offsets.

The address is relative to the *end* of the jump instruction, hence the SizeOf(NewCode) adjustment.

That code does look familiar to me. I think I wrote it!

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very clear! And yes I was reading your [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820294/how-can-i-make-allocatehwnd-threadsafe)